# Is there any inbuilt method for UPSERT in spring JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is there any inbuilt method for UPSERT in Spring JPA ?

Not the save() method which internally fired 2 query, 1. select and based on first query value it done insert or update.

My requirement is any method which fires UPSERT direct into the Database ?